# error: pointer value used where a floating point value was expected

Tags: c, pointers

This is not homework, but my last assignment made it clear that I didn't clearly understand pointers when coding C.

Therefore, I tried to type a simple program using pointers just to invert an integer in a function, so I could figure out where the gap in my understanding is.

Apparently, I've arrived at it, but I still cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

My source code is below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

float invert(int *num);

void main (void)
{
int num;
float a;

printf("enter an integer \n");

scanf("%i", &num);

printf("Number entered %i \n", num);

a=invert(&num);

printf("This is the invse from main %f \n", a);

}


float invert(int *num) /* function inverts integer */

{       
float invse;

printf("num is %i \n\n", *num);

invse = 1/(float)num;

printf("invse is %f \n\n", invse);

return(invse);

}
```

My thinking was that I used the pointer to direct the computer to use the value stored at the address for num in the function invert().  The pointer appears in the variable declaration.  I cast the value stored at that pointer as a float, so I could invert it, and store it in a local variable.

The problem appears to be in the local variable assignment.  My compiler returns "invert.c:29:2: error: pointer value used where a floating point value was expected
  invse = 1/(float)num;
  ^

Apparently my code indicates a pointer value for inverse, but I declared it as a float, which I find confusing.

Any help is appreciated.  This will save me on completing my larger set of code for my assignment, which I did not post here.

Thanks.

Comment: `num` is a pointer. `*num` is an int.  Try `invse = 1/(float)*num`

Comment: To be more explicit: `int v = *num; invse = 1 / (float)v;`

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the `printf` call inside `invert`

```
printf("num is %i \n\n", *num);
```

you already know that in order to access the value passed to `invert` for inversion you have to dereference `num` pointer: `*num`.

If so, then why aren't you dereferencing `num` when you perform the inversion itself?

```
invse = 1/(float)num;
```

I mean, if you are the one who wrote that `printf`, you should also realize that the actual inversion should be done as

```
invse = 1 / (float) *num;
```

or, alternatively, as

```
invse = 1.f / *num;
```

On top of being incorrect your original variant is illegal: you are not allowed to convert pointers to floating-point types in C, which is the reason for the error message.

P.S. From the bigger picture point of view, there's no real reason to pass that the number to `invert` by pointer. Passing the immediate value would make more sense

```
float invert(int num)
{
  ...
```

In that case you, of course, don't have to dereference anything inside `invert`.

Comment: Thanks Audrey!

Maybe I've been looking at code too long the last few days.

Yes, I wrote that printf.  Therefore, I SHOULD have realized the inversion required a ptr for invse=1/(float) *num.

It works now.

Thank you!